# Getting data out of Spark - Python

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have an rdd with about 50 million dicts in Spark 2.0. They are pretty small and only take up about 12Gb in memory (per Storage tab in Spark web UI). I've ran through all the processed I want on this RDD and now I want to pull it out from Spark because I now need to feed this data into another system.

I am getting nowhere with this and need some help. Ideally, what I want to do is send every partition to the driver and have it dump out data locally through another python module. This would require minimal additional coding.

I was hoping that something like this would work:

```
for x in processed_data.toDF().toLocalIterator():
    index.add(x)
```

But no joy, I got this handy stack trace:

```
<ipython-input-20-b347e9bd2075> in <module>()
----> 1 for x in processed_data.toDF().toLocalIterator():
      2     index.add(x)

/apps/spark2/python/pyspark/rdd.py in _load_from_socket(port, serializer)
    140     try:
    141         rf = sock.makefile("rb", 65536)
--> 142         for item in serializer.load_stream(rf):
    143             yield item
    144     finally:

/apps/spark2/python/pyspark/serializers.py in load_stream(self, stream)
    137         while True:
    138             try:
--> 139                 yield self._read_with_length(stream)
    140             except EOFError:
    141                 return

/apps/spark2/python/pyspark/serializers.py in _read_with_length(self, stream)
    154 
    155     def _read_with_length(self, stream):
--> 156         length = read_int(stream)
    157         if length == SpecialLengths.END_OF_DATA_SECTION:
    158             raise EOFError

/apps/spark2/python/pyspark/serializers.py in read_int(stream)
    541 
    542 def read_int(stream):
--> 543     length = stream.read(4)
    544     if not length:
    545         raise EOFError

/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py in readinto(self, b)
    372         while True:
    373             try:
--> 374                 return self._sock.recv_into(b)
    375             except timeout:
    376                 self._timeout_occurred = True

timeout: timed out
```

I checked all the log files and I have no idea what it could be. I've even tried to re partition the rdd so I have more smaller partitions and still no luck.

Since my driver has about 40GB of RAM allocated, I then tried to collect it, then I started getting a bunch of these:

```
ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running
tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to 
containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs 
for WARN messages.
```

I checked the logs and didn't even see any issues. 
The only thing that even remotely finished executing is writing the DF out to hdfs:

```
processed_data.toDF().write.json()
```

However the problem is that then I just get a dump of the data without proper JSON syntax, like commas after each object....

Am I missing something here? This is really frustrating because I've tried this with a smaller set of data and toLocalIterator was working great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is most likely just a symptom not a core problem.  Also why do you convert to `DataFrame` before collecting. It doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: I don't think rdd has a write method, its on the data frame. What is a good way to proceed troubleshooting some of these issues?

Comment: It provides a number of write methods and it still doesn't explain why you convert when you don't perform write. Re O `DataFrame.write.json` - provides a valid JSON document per line. There should no issue with reading it.

Comment: Are you talking about the various save methods here? http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD. Really, I would like to get the localIterator working, that is the best option. Any idea what it is timing out at?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is a known bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18281

It should be fixed in versions 2.0.3 and 2.1.1 (none of them is released yet, and 2.1 seems to have the bug still).

In the meantime, if memory is not an issue, replacing `toLocalIterator` by `collect` should work.